# Working with Elixir ETS across different processes

Tags: elixir, ets

I'm trying without much success to implement a really simple example around ETS. I want to have a number of `worker` processes write to an ETS table, and then have a single (and different) reader process retrieve values periodically as a sum. I can't seem to insert into the table without a crash, and the reader returns zero when ever it's executed...here's my code, any help very gratefully received:

The `Supervisor` module:

```
defmodule Stackex do
  use Application

  @noOfWriters 1

  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    Stackex.Reader.start_link
    Stackex.Table.start_link

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Stackex.Supervisor]

    children =
      for i <- 1..@noOfWriters do
        worker(Stackex.Writer, [i], id: i)
      end

    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)

  end
end
```

The `Writer` module:

```
defmodule Stackex.Writer do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(id) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__,{id})
  end

  def init({id}) do
    state = %{writer_id: id, value: value}
    schedule_work()
    {:ok, state}
  end

  def handle_info(:update, state) do
    Stackex.Table.add_kvp(state)
    update = %{writer_id: state.writer_id, value: value}
    schedule_work()
    {:noreply, update}
  end

  defp value do
    :random.seed(:erlang.now())
    :random.uniform(10) 
  end

  defp schedule_work() do
    Process.send_after(self, :update, 1000)
  end
end
```

The `Table` module:

```
defmodule Stackex.Table do
  use GenServer

  def start_link do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__,[], name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init do
    {:ok, :ets.new(:table, [:set, :named_table])}
  end

  #Client API
  def add_kvp(update) do
    GenServer.cast __MODULE__, {:load, update}
  end

  def get_kvp_sum do
    GenServer.call __MODULE__, {:sum}
  end

  ###### Server Callback Functions ########

  def handle_cast({:load, update}, state) do
    %{writer_id: key, value: value} = update
    {:noreply, :ets.insert(:table, {key, value})}
  end

  #Return total system load
  def handle_call({:sum}, _from, state) do
    sum = :ets.foldl(fn({{_,v}, acc}) -> v + acc end, 0, :table)
    {:reply, sum, state}
  end
end
```

The `Reader` module:

```
defmodule Stackex.Reader do
  use GenServer

  def start_link do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init do
    schedule_update
    {:ok, nil}
  end

  def handle_info(:update) do
    sum = Stackex.Table.get_kvp_sum
    IO.puts("Sum #{sum}")

    schedule_update
    {:noreply, nil}
  end

  defp schedule_update do
    Process.send_after(self, :update, 2000)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the question in the title, you can make a named ets table accessible to other processes by passing `:public` in the options when you call `:ets.new/2`

But according to the code you posted you do not have multiple processes accessing your table. There is only one `Stackex.Table` genserver started. Looks like you don't even need it to be a `:named_table` since you can just pass the pid in your `state` variable with very little change to your code.

Looks like your immediate problem is you are passing the wrong variable to you `add_kvp` method (`state` instead of `update`).